# how to scroll down if the records are more in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, scroll

I am having following hypelink control. If the records are more page has to scroll down for displaying last record. what to do?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" 
     onitemdatabound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%-- <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none" 
              Text='<%#Eval("ename") %>' >
       </asp:Label>--%>
       <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none" 
            Width="100px" ImageUrl=""   Text='<%#Eval("ename")  %>'>
       </asp:HyperLink>
       <asp:HiddenField Value='<%# Eval("ename") %>' ID="HiddenField1" 
            runat="server" />
       <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: If there are more records do you want to display last few records by automatically having the control scrolled down or just want to add a scroll bar if there are more records which do not fit the container. If you just need a scroll bar then you can wrap your repeater in a <div style="overflow-y:scroll"></div>.

Comment: thank you himanshu for your reply. My requirement is that page is displaying records and page view should be on the last displayed record..(by scrolling down the entire page) my records are fitting in container